# Dynamic Input Error To Mysql Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `student`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `student`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Here is the HTML part: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6utym536/)

And Here is the PHP part inserting data to mysql:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$connect) {
   echo mysql_error();
}
$db = mysql_select_db('demo');
if (!$db) {
  echo mysql_error();
} 
$all_names ="";
if(isset($_POST["mytext"])){   
   foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key => $text_field){
      $all_names .= $text_field .", ";
 }
}

$result = "INSERT INTO student ( name ) VALUES( $all_names )";
$insert_row  = mysql_query($result);
if(!$insert_row){
   echo $result;
}
```

Getting Error inserting value to database:

```
INSERT INTO student ( name ) VALUES( dffd, )
```

Comment: why Question with jQuery in title is not tagged with jQuery tag? and has no jQuery code included?

Comment: change `echo mysql_error();` to `echo $sql;` and show us results

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski It shows sql

Comment: @nikolas, of course it shows sql query. This is exactly what I need to see.

Comment: @nikolas, edit your question and paste this resulting query.

Comment: @nikolas, not `@sql` but `$sql`.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski, Oh sorry. Changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
   foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key => $text_field){
      $all_names .= $text_field .", ";
   }
```

to

```
$all_names = "'" . implode("'), ('", $_POST["mytext"]) . "'";
```

Comment: If you'd like to sanitize input then you could use `array_map` and `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: is it like `$all_names = "'" . implode("'), ('", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mytext"])) . "'"; `

Comment: No, something like `$all_names = "'" . implode("'), ('", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST["mytext"])) . "'"; `

Comment: Many Many thanks again. Another question: if I have another single value with it. How to save that field.

Comment: I do not understand. You want to `INSERT` not one, but two values into the table? Then probably it would be easier for you to modify @Alex code, but you could also continue using `implode` with earlier call to `array_walk`..

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Alex code working great with multiple values. You both are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see whole picture yet. What is the real value returned by `$_POST["mytext"]`?

But my guess you should at least change your loop to:

```
foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key => $text_field){
      if ($all_names == '') {
          $all_names .=  "( '".mysql_real_escape_string($text_field) ."') ";
      } else {
          $all_names .=  ",( '".mysql_real_escape_string($text_field) ."') ";
      }
 }
```

and your query to:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO student ( name ) VALUES $all_names ";
```

Comment: Same error:
INSERT INTO student ( name ) VALUES ,( 'dffd')

Comment: Comma is creating problem.

Comment: my bad typo in `if ($all_names == '') {`