# Multiple dynamic data input to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my html part

```
<form method="post" action="collect_vals.php">
    <div id="input_fields">
        <div><input type="text" name="name[]"> <input type="text" name="project[]"> <span class="fa fa-plus-circle" id="add_field"></span></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Details  on: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6utym536/11/)

I follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133197/dynamic-input-error-to-mysql-using-php) , it can save single field data. But how to insert multiple data to mysql.

How can i insert dynamic data to mysql?

Comment: I'm missing the question.

Comment: How can i insert dynamic data to mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access project names using the key, like this

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $key => $val)
{
    $proj = $_POST['project'][$key];
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (column1,colunm2) values ('$val','$proj')");
}
```

Comment: My code:
`if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["project"])){   
      foreach($_POST["name"] as $key => $text_field){
       $proj = $_POST['project'][$key];
      if ($all_names == '') {
          $all_names .=  "(".$proj.",'".mysql_real_escape_string($text_field) ."') ";
      } else {
          $all_names .=  ",(".$proj.", '".mysql_real_escape_string($text_field) ."') ";
      }
 }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO student (id, name ) VALUES $all_names ";
`
How to add your code

Comment: Single value input correctly. But project not inputed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92370/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-nikolas).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` on PHP side. Your HTML part is good.

Here is an example:

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $a)
    {
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) values ('$a')");
    }
```

Comment: what about for project part?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="collect_vals.php">
    <div id="input_fields">
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="name[]"> 
        <input type="text" name="project[]"> 
        <span class="fa fa-plus-circle" id="add_field"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**collect_vals.php**

```
<?
extract($_POST);

$SizeOfName=sizeof($name);
for($i=0;$i<$SizeOfName;$i++)
{
    $Name=$name[$i];
    $Project=$project[$i];

    $QueryInsert="INSERT INTO TableName SET NameColumnName='$Name',ProjectColumnName='$Project'";
}
?>
```